Custom Fonts Not applied in LWR Experience Community Site Salesforce
I have created a community site in Salesforce (LWR) and need to use custom fonts.
I have uploaded both ttf and otf format of custom font files as 2 different static resources and tried using either of those but it does not work.
I have added the CSS code to declare the font-family and the path using the src as follows, but no success.
Is there something I need to do differently?
Tried all the following:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JerseyFont';
    src: url('/messaging/s/resource/Jersey_Font/Jersey10-Regular.ttf');
}
    
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JerseyFont';
    src: url('resource/Jersey_Font/Jersey10-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'JerseyFont';
    src: url('/messaging/s/sfsites/c/resource/Jersey_Font/Jersey10-Regular.ttf');
}
    
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JerseyFont';
    src: url('resource/Jersey_Font/Jersey10-Regular.ttf');
}



I tried this in the head markup and it worked for me
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'myFirstFont';
        /* Replace myFont with your resource name */
        src: url('{ basePath }/sfsites/c/resource/customFontNew') format('truetype');
    }
</style>

The format type for ttf files is truetype
